# React print a component

Tags: reactjs

There is a 'Print' button on SaleInvoice.js which shows the Modal containing Report.js.

Report.js is created only to describe how and what should be displayed in the printed page.

Report.js has a button 'Print' which opens the Print Preview in the browser.

How do I make the 'Print' button on SaleInvoice.js directly open the Print Preview in the browser?

> SaleInvoice.js

```
...
            <button
              style={{marginRight: '200px'}}
              onClick={() => this.setState({printView: true})}>
              Print
            </button>
            {this.state.printView ? (
              <Modal
                type="Print"
                {...this.props}
                show={this.state.printView}
                modalClosed={() => this.setState({printView: false})}
              />
            ) : null}
...
```

> Report.js

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './SaleInvoice.module.css';

const SaleInvoice = props => {
  const {customerName} = props;
  const rows = props.lineItems;
  const alignRightMarginRight = [styles.alignRight, styles.marginRight].join(
    ' ',
  );
  const {amountBeforeFreight, freight, amountAfterFreight} = props;
  const reverseDateString = date => {
    let [yyyy, mm, dd] = date.split('-');
    return dd + '-' + mm + '-' + yyyy;
  };
  const renderContent = () => {
    let i = 0;
    let contentRows = (i, d) => {
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <td className={styles.serialNumber}>{i}</td>
          <td className={styles.productName}>{d.product_name}</td>
          <td className={alignRightMarginRight}>{d.product_qty}</td>
          <td className={alignRightMarginRight}>{d.product_unit}</td>
          <td className={alignRightMarginRight}>{d.product_rate}</td>
          <td className={alignRightMarginRight}>{d.product_disc}</td>
          <td className={alignRightMarginRight}>{d.sub_total}</td>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    };
    return rows.map(d => {
      i++;
      if (i === rows.length) {
        return null;
      }
      if (i % 10 === 0) {
        return (
          <tr key={i} className={styles.pagebreak}>
            {contentRows(i, d)}
          </tr>
        );
      } else {
        return <tr key={i}>{contentRows(i, d)}</tr>;
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className={styles.all}>
        <div className={[styles.header].join(' ')}>
          <button className={styles.hideInPrint} onClick={window.print}>
            Print
          </button>
          <button className={styles.hideInPrint} onClick={props.modalClosed}>
            Close
          </button>
          <h5 className={styles.docTitle}>Estimate</h5>
          <h6 className={styles.customerName}>
            {customerName}
            <span className={styles.date}>
              {reverseDateString(props.date.split('T')[0])}
            </span>
          </h6>
        </div>
        <table className={styles.content}>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>No</td>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td className={alignRightMarginRight}>Qty</td>
              <td className={alignRightMarginRight}>Unit</td>
              <td className={alignRightMarginRight}>Rate</td>
              <td className={alignRightMarginRight}>Disc</td>
              <td className={alignRightMarginRight}>Total</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody className={styles.content}>{renderContent()}</tbody>
        </table>
        <div className={styles.footer}>
          <div className={styles.foot}>
            <label>Amount:</label>
            <label className={styles.amount}>
              {amountBeforeFreight.toFixed(2)}
            </label>
          </div>
          <div className={styles.foot}>
            <label>Freight:</label>
            <label className={styles.amount}>
              {freight ? freight.toFixed(2) : 0}
            </label>
          </div>
          <div className={styles.foot}>
            <label>Final Amount:</label>
            <label className={styles.amount}>
              {amountAfterFreight.toFixed(2)}
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default SaleInvoice;
```

Comment: Hi, did you get any solution?@rounak jain

Answer (score 0):

in your file SalesInvoice.js, we would be changing the event onClick, instead of what action does(setting modal view to true in your state) we want it to open the print window in the browser.
as follows

```
<button
  style={{marginRight: '200px'}}
  onClick={window.print} >
  Print
</button>
```

you will not need this part I guess?

```
        {this.state.printView ? (
          <Modal
            type="Print"
            {...this.props}
            show={this.state.printView}
            modalClosed={() => this.setState({printView: false})}
          />
        ) : null}
```

Comment: No, that would print SaleInvoice.js not Report.js

Comment: `window.print()` will make a screenshot kind of print copy to the elements shown inside the `document` that `window` holds, to the best I know we cant let it print something that is not mounted in the DOM.